# C# Invoking causes Task never complete

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is my code:

```
public void ReadCodes(){
        Task compute = Task.Run(() =>
        {
             //foo code
             foreach (var line in lines)
             {
                 //some other codes
                 SetText("doing something");
             }
        });
        compute.Wait();
        //some other foo
}
private void SetText(string text)
{
        if (this.lblUsedFiles.InvokeRequired)
        {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
                this.lblUsedFiles.Text = text;
        }
}
```

When I remove `SetText("doing something")` call `ReadCodes()` function works, otherwise it hangs. What's wrong with my code? I want to update UI inside `Task.Run()`.

Comment: `Wait` blocks main thread, so the `Invoke`d code can't be scheduled.

Comment: In other words you have deadlock.

Comment: `Task.Run` followed by a `task.Wait` can be completely ignored. You get no benefits from it. Simply invoke the method synchronously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ReadCodes` method (which presumably executes on the UI thread) spawns a new task, and blocks to wait for it – the UI thread can do nothing else until it completes.

However, your task (which runs on the thread pool) calls `Invoke` to run an operation on the UI thread, also blocking until this completes. Since both operations are blocked waiting for each other, neither can proceed, resulting in a deadlock.

To resolve, the easiest solution is typically to replace your `Invoke` with `BeginInvoke`, allowing your task to proceed (and complete) without waiting for the UI update. Once the task does complete, the UI thread is freed, and processes the pending UI update.

**Edit**: In response to the question being updated to include a loop: I would suggest that you use the asynchronous pattern (introduced in C# 5). This would eliminate UI thread blocking altogether, and allow you to perform UI updates as soon as each line is processed.

```
public async Task ReadCodes()
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string text = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //foo code
            // return text;
        });

        this.lblUsedFiles.Text = text;
    }
    //some other foo
}
```

**Edit<sub>2</sub>**: I've updated my code based on [Peter Duniho's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075547/c-sharp-invoking-causes-task-never-complete/27075685?noredirect=1#comment42673990_27075685). Since `ReadCodes` is presumably called on the UI thread, you can update the UI directly within it (without needing `Invoke`) upon awaiting each task. I'm assuming that the background processing performed in `//some other codes` can be integrated into the subsequent iteration's `//foo code`.

Comment: It fixes hang problem, but it does not update UI on every iteration inside `Task.Run()`, because `SetText()` is actually called inside a `foreeach` loop, it updates the UI on the latest iteration only.

Comment: The main issue isn't the `Invoke`, it's calling `Wait` on the main thread.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I want to wait for running codes inside `Task.Run()` gets completed, and at the same time updating UI.

Comment: Actually, the best `async` solution would get rid of the `Invoke()` altogether. I.e. recompose the asynchronous `//foo code`, and possibly the `//some other codes` depending on what it is, so that the `this.lblUsedFiles.Text = text;` statement is actually in the `ReadCodes()` method, called after awaiting each `//foo code` task.